# Неопределенная ссылка на aio_read, aio_error и тд

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - компилятор не хочет компилировать строчки

```
aio_read(operations[i].aio)
aio_error(operations[i].aio)
```

и тому подобное, пишет: неопределённая ссылка на «aio_read»

Пишу на VS Code, но CodeBlocks выдает тот же результат.
Есть структура

```
struct aio_operation {
    struct aiocb* aio;
    char *buffer;
    int write_operation;
};
```

И есть массив с типом этой самой структуры (processesCount просто число, а fileHandler - дескриптор, который мы получили с открытого файла -
`fileHandler = open(filePath, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, 0666);` )

```
struct aio_operation* operations;
operations = calloc(processesCount, sizeof(struct aio_operation));

for (int i = 0; i < processesCount; i++)
    {
        operations[i].aio = malloc(sizeof(struct aiocb));
        memset(operations[i].aio, 0, sizeof(*(operations[i].aio)));

        operations[i].write_operation = 0;
        operations[i].buffer = (char*)calloc(cluster,sizeof(char));
        operations[i].aio->aio_fildes = fileHandler;
        operations[i].aio->aio_nbytes = cluster;
        operations[i].aio->aio_offset = 0;
        operations[i].aio->aio_buf = operations[i].buffer;
        
        if (aio_read(operations[i].aio) == -1)
        {
            puts("Error: Can't async read file");
            freeMemory(operations, processesCount);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Поле aio в структуре заполняется правильно (проверял с помощью printf), и дескриптор тоже без проблем считывается и проходит проверку через if. Полагаю, что где то мог накосячить с компилятором, так как сам с линуксом на вы. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Покажи реализацию `aio_read`

Comment: Компонуется при указании параметра -lrt. Если это - это это https://ru.manpages.org/aio_read/3 то нужно в LD_FLAGS добавить -lrt.